# Shoppe commerce and stripe payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, stripe-payments

Trying to integrate Shoppe(https://github.com/tryshoppe/shoppe) and Stripe payment (https://github.com/tryshoppe/shoppe-stripe) onto my Rails application by following this Docs/Tutorial (https://tryshoppe.com/docs/payment-gateways/stripe). Not sure why im getting this error...

> Couldn't find Shoppe::Order with 'id'=

```
def payment
 @order = Shoppe::Order.find(session[:current_order_id])
 if request.post?
 if @order.accept_stripe_token(params[:stripe_token])
 redirect_to checkout_confirmation_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that it can't find a `Shopped::Order` with an id of nothing.

This means the argument `session[:current_order_id]` contains no information.

You need to look into correcting whatever is causing the value that correlates with the `:current_order_id` key in the `session` hash to be blank.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in the shoppe documentation.  In order to access current_order you need to create the helper in your ApplicationController like so. I then suggest referencing as current_order.id instead.

ApplicationController:

```
private

  def current_order
    @current_order ||= begin
      if has_order?
        @current_order
      else
        order = Shoppe::Order.create(:ip_address => request.ip)
        session[:order_id] = order.id
        order
      end
    end
  end

  def has_order?
    session[:order_id] && @current_order = Shoppe::Order.includes(:order_items => :ordered_item).find_by_id(session[:order_id])
  end

  helper_method :current_order, :has_order?
```

OrdersController:

```
def payment
  @order = Shoppe::Order.find(current_order.id)
  ### rest of your code here ###
end
```